Can the error 'error communicating with TMP chip' impact performance?
I just installed ubuntu onto an HP Z-820. During boot, the message
error communicating with TPM chip
flashes about 8 times. The boot continues seemingly without a problem. I'm now just doing the usual update after installation, and it is incredibly slow.Could theses two issues (error and performance during upgrade) be related?
Thanks
